# Evaluate $\frac{(5+6)(5^2+6^2)(5^4+6^4)\cdots(5^{1024}+6^{1024})+5^{2048}}{3^{1024}}$

Tags: exponentiation

Evaluate $$\frac{(5+6)(5^2+6^2)(5^4+6^4)\cdot\dots\cdot(5^{1024}+6^{1024})+5^{2048}}{3^{1024}}.$$

I can't figure out where to start. I tried using logarithms but I couldn't get a pattern going. Any advice will be helpful, thanks in advanced.

Comment: Did you try cases where the exponents are much smaller?  For example, what is $\frac {(5+6)(5^2+6^2)+5^4}{3^2}$?  I see a pattern here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{(5+6)+5^2}{3^1}=12$$

$$\frac{(5+6)(5^2+6^2)+5^4}{3^2}=144=12^2$$

$$\frac{(5+6)(5^2+6^2)(5^4+6^4)+5^8}{3^4}=20736=12^4$$

There is a pattern there. See if you can prove that the pattern continues.

---

One way is to generalize how something like $(5+6)(5^2+6^2)+5^4$ squares to become equal to $(5+6)(5^2+6^2)(5^4+6^4)+5^8$. [Because then just square both sides of one of the above equations to get to the next equation.]

As in:
$$
\begin{align}
\left((5+6)(5^2+6^2)+5^4\right)^2&=(5+6)^2(5^2+6^2)^2+2(5+6)(5^2+6^2)5^4+5^8\\
&=(5+6)(5^2+6^2)\left[(5+6)(5^2+6^2)+2(5^4)\right]+5^8
\end{align}
$$

So now it is about generalizing that something like $(5+6)(5^2+6^2)+2(5^4)$ is the same as $(5^4+6^4)$. I think writing all the $6$'s as $5+1$ and using the binomial theorem might get you there.

Comment: Holy smokes how do you even think about something like that?! Thank you Alex.Jordan

Comment: @JoshuaBonet:  when I see a long chain like this I tend to try small cases.  I got Excel to do the calcs-copy down made it quick.

Answer (score 1):

Hint  -  telescope:

$$
\begin{align}
&\quad \frac{\big(\color{red}{(6-5)\cdot}(6+5)\big)\;(6^2+5^2)(6^4+5^4)\cdot\dots\cdot(6^{1024}+5^{1024})+5^{2048}}{\color{red}{(6-5)\cdot}3^{1024}} \\
&= \frac{\big((6^2-5^2)(6^2+5^2)\big)\;(6^4+5^4)\cdot\dots\cdot(6^{1024}+5^{1024})+5^{2048}}{3^{1024}} \\
&= \frac{\big((6^4-5^4)(6^4+5^4)\big)\;(6^8+5^8)\cdot\dots\cdot(6^{1024}+5^{1024})+5^{2048}}{3^{1024}} \\
 &= \;\ldots
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

First we simplify the numerator of $$ \frac{(5+6)(5^2+6^2)(5^4+6^4)\cdot\dots\cdot(5^{1024}+6^{1024})+5^{2048}}{3^{1024}}.$$

$$(5+6)(5^2+6^2)=(6-5)(5+6)(5^2+6^2)=(6^4-5^4)$$

$$(5+6)(5^2+6^2)(5^4+6^4)=(6^4-5^4)((5^4+6^4)=(6^8-5^8)
\\.\\.\\ (5+6)(5^2+6^2)(5^4+6^4)\cdot\dots\cdot(5^{1024}+6^{1024})=(6^{2048}-5^{2048})$$
$$ \frac{(5+6)(5^2+6^2)(5^4+6^4)\cdot\dots\cdot(5^{1024}+6^{1024})+5^{2048}}{3^{1024}}=\frac {  6^{2048} }{ 3^{1024}} = 12^{1024} $$